# Counting most prevalent item in dictionary of lists python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
dict_users = {
    "user1": ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item1", "item2", "elem3", "thing4", "thing5", "thing6"],
    "user2": ["elem5", "elem8", "elem2", "elem3", "elem8", "elem5", "thing7", "thing1", "thing9"],
    "user3": ["thing9", "thing7", "thing1", "thing4", "elem3", "elem9", "thing3", "thing5", "thing2"],
}
```

Now from here, I would like to build a new dictionary that couples the users to the item that is used the most in their list, so in this case the output for the example would be:

```
dict_counted = {
'user1': 'item'
'user2': 'elem'
'user3': 'thing'
}
```

I now have something like this:

```
users = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']

dictOfRatios = dict.fromkeys(users)

for key, value in dict_users.items():
    for value in dict_sers[key]:
        if value.startswith("item"):
            itemlist = list(value)
            for user in dictOfRatios:
                dictOfRatios[user] = len(itemlist)
                
print(dictOfRatios)
```

But the ouptut is not as desired and it even gives the wrong number...
The criteria for matching in this case could be anything ranging from i, e, t to complete item, elem, thing.

Comment: Please provide valid sample data; your `dict_users` is not valid Python.

Comment: To debug your current code, check out [these suggestions](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Alternatively, look at [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: @ThierryLathuille `dict_users` looks like valid Python syntax to me. There are undeclared name errors, but the syntax is fine. Probably the easiest change to make this work is to just make them strings by adding quotes around each item.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice  Looking at the rest of the question, it seems that it should be a list of string litterals - but the quotes are missing....

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.
Your input list consists of undefined symbols; your process rationale is unclear, and you haven't presented any execution or value trace.  "The output is not as desired" is not a problem specification, especially when your code won't run.

Comment: your question not well defined - does all keys must start with one of the following: item, elem, thing? if they may vary - what are the logic to define as a prefix? let's say for `itemqq` and `it23`, does `it` is sufficient suffix?

Comment: I feel the question is fine. OP has also edited the syntax errors.

Comment: What happens when different items show up the same number of times? (How do you deal with ties?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python [counter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is what you need

```py
from collections import Counter
import re

dict_users = {
'user1': ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item1', 'item2', 'elem3', 'thing4', 'thing5', 'thing6'],
'user2': ['elem5', 'elem8', 'elem2', 'elem3', 'elem8', 'elem5', 'thing7', 'thing1', 'thing9'],
'user3': ['thing9', 'thing7', 'thing1', 'thing4', 'elem3', 'elem9', 'thing3', 'thing5', 'thing2']
}

users = {user: Counter() for user in dict_users.keys()}

for us, lst in dict_users.items():
    user_counter = users[us]
    for el in lst:
        item_name = re.split("\d",el)[0]
        user_counter[item_name] += 1

dict_counted = {user: counter.most_common(1)[0][0] for user, counter in users.items()}
print(dict_counted)
```

Outputs:

```
{
 'user1': 'item',
 'user2': 'elem',
 'user3': 'thing'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code -

`itemlist = list(value)`

This will set the same list again to item list. When you do len on it, you will get the length of the full list.

This will solve your problem

```
dict_users = {'user1': ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item1', 'item2', 'elem3', 'thing4', 'thing5', 'thing6'],'user2': ['elem5', 'elem8', 'elem2', 'elem3', 'elem8', 'elem5', 'thing7', 'thing1', 'thing9'],'user3': ['thing9', 'thing7', 'thing1', 'thing4', 'elem3', 'elem9', 'thing3', 'thing5', 'thing2']}

new_dict = {}
for user, value in dict_users.items():
    item_count = sum([1 for each in value if each.startswith('item')])
    elem_count = sum([1 for each in value if each.startswith('elem')])
    thing_count = sum([1 for each in value if each.startswith('user')])
    max_count = item_count
    new_value = 'item'
    if elem_count > max_count:
        max_count = elem_count
        new_value = 'elem'
    if  thing_count > max_count:
        max_count = thing_count
        new_value = 'thing'
    new_dict[user]  = new_value
```

Edit:

Just saw that the list values may have single characters to denote `item`, `elem` & `thing`.

Look into regex and how to match with it. The same code but instead of using `startswith`, use regex to match.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dict_users = {
    'user1': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
    'user2': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2'],
    'user3': ['!', '!', '!', '!', '@', '@', '@', '@', '@']
}

unique_values = {}
final_dict = {}

for key, value in dict_users.items():
    unique_values[key] = set(value)

count = 0
for key, value in unique_values.items():
    for el in value:
        if dict_users[key].count(el) > count:
            count = dict_users[key].count(el)
        final_dict[key] = el

print(final_dict)
```

This gives takes the dictionary,

```
dict_users = {
    'user1': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
    'user2': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2'],
    'user3': ['!', '!', '!', '!', '@', '@', '@', '@', '@']
}
```

and gives you,

```
{'user1': 'a', 'user2': '2', 'user3': '@'}
```

I hope this is what you have wanted to achieve. :)